# strstr with regular char array , not strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, strstr

I tried to create a function which works the same as strstr , but with char arrays instead of strings and returning 1 if the first array is in the second array
(the programming language is c).
I have the declaration of the function added.`int arrInArr(char *a, char *b ,int lenA , int lenB);`

Comment: Can you show us the implementation i.e. your code?

Comment: "char arrays instead of strings" - Please explain the difference.

Comment: I read the code of the original strstr function and saw it requires the '\0' at the end of the string, 
Jonathon with strings you have the '\0' at the end which is required for the check

Comment: Maybe your are searching `man strchr(3)` ??!
Strings are char array in c

Comment: PandaCool I know they are char arrays but I need a function similar to strstr that will work with any char array. not only strings

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: C strings are *null terminated* char arrays. Not all char arrays are strings.

Comment: You mean like double/triple/... char array ?

Comment: No, like finding a subarray inside an array (with it not being a string). Can be a char array that is not null terminated, an integers array or a floats array

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are looking for the `memmem` function. Extracts from the man page:

> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> void *
>  memmem(const void *big, size_t big_len, const void *little,
>      size_t little_len);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The memmem() function locates the first occurrence of the byte string
>        little in the byte string big.

Disclaimer: this function is not member of C standard library but exists at least in BSD and Linux - even it is declared as broken until glibc 2.1

Comment: Is `memmem` standard ?

Comment: I will try that and will be right back

Comment: the compiler doesn't know memmem and the code now won't compile

Comment: `memmem` is a GNU extension.

Comment: @KorenX: what is your compiler?

Comment: my compiler is gcc

Comment: @KorenX It weird that gcc does not know about what is called a *GNU extension*... What is the exact version and platform? And did you include string.h

Comment: You need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: thanks for the comment. I've included it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an non-optimized implementation of `arrInArr`. I changed the parameter types slightly.

```
#include <string.h>

int arrInArr(const char *a, const char *b, size_t len_a, size_t len_b)
{
    size_t n;

    if (len_a > len_b)
        return 0;

    for (n = 0; n <= len_b - len_a; n++)
    {
        if (memcmp(&b[n], a, len_a) == 0)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in my code it has a bit of a problem with an array I took from a .jpg file

Comment: Oh, reading your question again, you want to find the first sequence (`a`) within the second sequence (`b`), but my function did it the other way round. I've edited it now to find `a` within `b`. Does that work any better for you?